# convert SHA1 byte output to character string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to match the output of the SHA1 function that I performed on a column in one of my tables to already hashed values in another table in the sql database. However- the other table contains the hashed values as character strings and so they dont match to the byte values that the SHA1 function output.

Do you know how I can convert the output which is in bytes to character strings?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried... CONVERT?

Comment: I just did.. and it worked! thanks you! Particularly: CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),HashBytes('SHA1', --column to hash---),2)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!